# MacOS Mojave update deleted calendar events

Tags: calendar, mojave

I've just installed the macOS Mojave on my late 2013 MacBook Pro, and it's deleted **all** of my calendar events, past, present, and future. My calendar now looks brand new, and not even the newly installed Siri can help me.

How do I retrieve my lost calendar events?

Comment: where those Google calendars ? do you use iCloud ?

Comment: No - the built in Mac calendar. And no, I don't use iCloud (but now I wish I did!).

Comment: OK, hang on till I look for it

Comment: hmm they all say you need iCloud